# drupal theming a view for Customfield: PHP code

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-fields

I have a view called "contests_slider" with a block display. I'm hiding all fields and using a "Customfield: PHP code" field instead which calls a function called display_front_contests(). In that function, querying the database and building some html and returning it. I'm displaying the output in a block. The problem is Drupal is adding alot of extra divs that I don't want. I went to "Theme: Information" and copied the theme "views-view-field.tpl.php" to "views-view-field--contests-slider--block-1--phpcode.tpl.php" and put just:  in it and it's still outputting all the extra html.
Any ideas? am I using the wrong template?

Comment: Have you cleaned the Theme registry cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only using views to create a block, but otherwise query the datebase, create the markup etc, you should consider making a block in a custom module. All the work is in the code you have already written. That way you wont have to think about the many templates that views uses, but instead you'll just use the `block.tpl.php`.

Take a look at [`hook_block`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_block/6) for info on how to do it.